# Grouping by date and time values from a DateTime value in SSRS in 24 hour format

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have a Stored Procedure which will be returning the columns **Date**( in yyyy/mm/DD HH:mm:ss format),**Names** and **Data**. When I'm making the Date part of **Date**(in MM/dd/yyyy format  as parent row group ,Time part of **Date** as child row group and **Name**  as column group and **Data** as the value in the matrix, I'm getting the time values consistently  from 1:00 ,1:30,2:00,2:30 .. to 11:30 and it is displaying 23:59,12:00, 00:30 and jumping to the other **Date** group instead of staring from 00:30,01:00 ...to 11:30 and continuing as 12:00,12:30,13:00 to 23:59. The SP results will contain the time for one of the names from 00:30,01;00,01:30 to 23:30 and 23:59 and the other name will  have  times as 01:00,02:00 to 23:00 and 23:59.

I'm getting the values correctly up to only 11:30 starting from 01:00. I need the time values to be  00:30,01:00,01:30...12:00,12:30...23:00,23:59

Note:(since grouping is involved and one of the name's time does not equals other, 0 will be displayed in those cells - It is also working fine but only up to time 11:00 and it is displaying 23:59,12:00,00:30 and jumping to the other **Date** group

Can someone please help on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have sorted the results. So the time is displaying from 00:30,01:00 ... to 12:00 and it is displaying only 23:59 missing 12:30 to 23:30

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are grouping for time in a 12-hour format but not including the period (AM/PM) which is `tt` in the formatting.

`hh` is for a 12 hour so you would need to add the `tt`

```
=FORMAT(Fields!DATE_FIELD, "hh:mm tt"
```

`HH` is for a 12 hour so you would not need to add the `tt`

```
=FORMAT(Fields!DATE_FIELD, "HH:mm"
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be the type of grouping. I have used date for one of the groups and string type for other group. Now I have changed both to string and it is working fine.